# X-Accel-Redirect doesn't work with python3 and Django 1.5 with non ascii filenames

Tags: django, python-3.x, uwsgi

I wanted to try Django with python 3.

I use:

- Nginx
- uWSGI + python 3 plugin from Ubuntu repos
- python 3.2
- virtualenv

When I made it for python 2.7 I had this and it worked:

```
...
fname_ascii = fname.encode('utf-8')
response = HttpResponse()
response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = _convert_file_to_url(fname_ascii)
```

Now with python 3 I replaced 1 line to:

```
response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = bytes(_convert_file_to_url(fname), 'utf-8')
```

And this caused:

```
Sat Apr  6 11:27:30 2013 - !!! uWSGI process 6296 got Segmentation Fault !!!
Sat Apr  6 11:27:30 2013 - *** backtrace of 6296 ***
Sat Apr  6 11:27:30 2013 - /usr/bin/uwsgi(uwsgi_backtrace+0x25) [0x430a55]
Sat Apr  6 11:27:30 2013 - /usr/bin/uwsgi(uwsgi_segfault+0x21) [0x430b31]
Sat Apr  6 11:27:30 2013 - /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x364a0) [0x7f2177f544a0]
Sat Apr  6 11:27:30 2013 - /usr/lib/libpython3.2mu.so.1.0(PyBytes_AsString+0) [0x7f217417e280]
Sat Apr  6 11:27:30 2013 - /usr/lib/uwsgi/plugins/python32_plugin.so(py_uwsgi_spit+0x45f) [0x7f217455c5ef]
Sat Apr  6 11:27:30 2013 - /usr/lib/libpython3.2mu.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x6230) [0x7f217405f310]
Sat Apr  6 11:27:30 2013 - /usr/lib/libpython3.2mu.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x687) [0x7f21741289e7]
Sat Apr  6 11:27:30 2013 - /usr/lib/libpython3.2mu.so.1.0(+0x12acff) [0x7f2174128cff]
Sat Apr  6 11:27:30 2013 - /usr/lib/libpython3.2mu.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0x7a) [0x7f217413f8aa]
Sat Apr  6 11:27:30 2013 - /usr/lib/libpython3.2mu.so.1.0(+0xac98d) [0x7f21740aa98d]
Sat Apr  6 11:27:30 2013 - /usr/lib/libpython3.2mu.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0x7a) [0x7f217413f8aa]
Sat Apr  6 11:27:30 2013 - /usr/lib/libpython3.2mu.so.1.0(+0xc773c) [0x7f21740c573c]
Sat Apr  6 11:27:30 2013 - /usr/lib/libpython3.2mu.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0x7a) [0x7f217413f8aa]
Sat Apr  6 11:27:30 2013 - /usr/lib/libpython3.2mu.so.1.0(PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords+0x47) [0x7f2174180cb7]
Sat Apr  6 11:27:30 2013 - /usr/lib/uwsgi/plugins/python32_plugin.so(python_call+0x24) [0x7f21745592f4]
Sat Apr  6 11:27:30 2013 - /usr/lib/uwsgi/plugins/python32_plugin.so(uwsgi_request_wsgi+0x119) [0x7f217455b6c9]
Sat Apr  6 11:27:30 2013 - /usr/bin/uwsgi(wsgi_req_recv+0x7f) [0x40dd5f]
Sat Apr  6 11:27:30 2013 - /usr/bin/uwsgi(simple_loop+0x112) [0x42be12]
Sat Apr  6 11:27:30 2013 - /usr/bin/uwsgi(uwsgi_ignition+0x18a) [0x430faa]
Sat Apr  6 11:27:30 2013 - /usr/bin/uwsgi(uwsgi_start+0x2c36) [0x434586]
Sat Apr  6 11:27:30 2013 - /usr/bin/uwsgi(main+0xed4) [0x40d6e4]
Sat Apr  6 11:27:30 2013 - /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed) [0x7f2177f3f76d]
Sat Apr  6 11:27:30 2013 - /usr/bin/uwsgi() [0x40d781]
Sat Apr  6 11:27:30 2013 - *** end of backtrace ***
Sat Apr  6 11:27:30 2013 - DAMN ! worker 2 (pid: 6296) died :( trying respawn ...
Sat Apr  6 11:27:30 2013 - Respawned uWSGI worker 2 (new pid: 6299)
```

I also tried just:

```
response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = _convert_file_to_url(fname)
```

but got:

```
BadHeaderError at /my_url

Header values can't contain newlines (got '=?utf-8?b?...=?=\n =?utf-8....=?=\n =?utf-8?b?...=?=')
```

uWSGI settings changed:

```
[uwsgi]
...
plugins = python32
virtualenv = /pyenvs/p3_general/
```

If someone had this problem - write what you know.
Or maybe it is just a bug. But it seems it is a uwsgi-plugin's bug.

**Update 1:**

I installed uwsgi 1.9.5 using pip:

```
Starting uWSGI 1.9.5 (64bit) on [Sat Apr  6 16:27:03 2013] 
...
Python version: 3.2.3 (default, Oct 19 2012, 19:55:38)  [GCC 4.7.2]
```

The same problem.

**And I forgot to mention - this happens only with filenames that have non-ascii symbols (russian in my case)**

**UPDATE 2:**

Using `urllib.parse.quote` uWSGI works but Nginx gives errors:

- `failed (36: File name too long)`  (fixed easily)
- `open() "/data/SORT/%D1%84%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D1%84%D1%8B.ogg" failed (2: No such file or directory)`

So the problem I think is - **uWSGI + python 3**

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you to use a uWSGI stable version (1.4 or 1.9 tree). The debian supplied version is very old and with various known bugs

Comment: I just installed 1.9.5 - the same problem

Comment: can you double check if you are really using the 1.9.5 (it is reported in startup logs). I cannot reproduce your problem in recent versions

Comment: Yes, 1.9.5. I forgot to mention - this happens only with filenames that have non-ascii symbols (russian in my case)

Comment: hmm this is an interesting problem. Headers (in pep3333) should be forced to latin1, and i suppose doing it for russian chars is not possible (the segfault is very probably generated by the wrong/undone conversion). What about url_encoding the filename before generating the header ? I do not know if it is good for nginx

Comment: Used `urllib.parse.quote_plus(myurl, '/')` - uwsgi didn't crash but Nginx gives 404 (will dig in this direction). The interesting part is that it worked with python 2.7 - I just decoded unicode filename to ascii string, now I tried `bytes()` but it fails always.

Comment: Used `urllib.parse.quote` (and `quote_plus` too)

Comment: The problem is very 'hard' to solve: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3333/#unicode-issues maybe the best (read: no brainer) is using uWSGI offloading, add --offload-threads = N to your uWSGI options and then simply use wsgi.file_wrapper facilitiy